# Molecular MC simulation is not equilibrating

Tags: python, monte-carlo, polymers, atomistic-simulation

Suppose, a polymer has *N* monomers in its chain. I want to simulate its movement using the **bead-spring** model.

So, I wrote the following program in ***Python***.

- [Polymer chain simulation with Monte Carlo method](https://github.com/mns-csharp/PolymerSimulation__Python/blob/master/polymer.py)

I am using 0.1 million steps. The energy is not fluctuating as expected. After several steps, the curve goes totally flat.

[image]

The X-axis is steps. Y-axis is total energy.

Can anyone check the source code and tell me what I should change?

N.B. I am especially concerned with the function that calculates the total energy of the polymer.

Comment: My last advice would be to write it in a friendlier language, or, more common language. Python/Matlab/Julia are the best for trying new things, and many people don't mind looking at codes written in these languages. C# is not that common for modelling. Last Last advice, make a polymer made of only two beads, calculate the energy for several snapshots by hand, and compare with the program.

Comment: Do your beads stop moving when it goes flat? If so, perhaps your random number generator breaks. print to screen the random number used in the metropolis criteria, as well as the math.exp(-(energy_new-energy_old)/T), see which one of those stops changing. Also print to screen the X and Y positions to see if they stop changing

Comment: If the beads stop moving, you need to figure out if it is because new positions aren't being generated correctly, or, new positions arent being accepted correctly. If positions aren't being generated correctly - probably random number generator issue. If moves aren't being accepted, it could be random number generator issue, or potential energy calculation issue, but since potential energy seems to work before, that would be odd. If your energies are dimensionless as they appear, and really are raised to the thousand, that may be an issue. that is a big number for a single molecule

Comment: Not sure what the best chat room for this would be.

Comment: In `get_potential` the `if` statement at line 118 and the `else` statement at line 121 don't make sense to me. It seems to say, if the two particles are not the same, apply the morse potential, if they are the same, apply harmonic potential? Further, the if statements inside the `else` statement at line 121 don't do what you want, I don't think. I will try running it and playing with it later

Comment: @NikeDattani this is probably fine, we can delete all the older stuff. It was for the original question, which has been modified now

Comment: @B.Kelly, *It seems to say, if the two particles are not the same, apply the morse potential, if they are the same, apply harmonic potential?* --- Exactly! Consider one atom. When it is compared with itself, the pair-potential cannot be derived. So, at that point, we have the opportunity to add the potentials of two springs on its either side.

Comment: @user366312 right, but it is applying the morse potential, is it not, rather than doing nothing, if the two particles are the same particle? Pair interactions are for pairs of different particles, a particle does not have potential energy with itself

Comment: @B.Kelly, if you consider the entire operation on one atom, it is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing. Coz an atom is compared with itself only once.

Comment: an atom interacting with itself is separated by `0` distance. if you pass this to `morse`, it then calculates `diff_float = r_float - min_atom_distance_float`, which doesn't make sense. You should be skipping self interactions, not calculating their morse potential at a `-min_atom_distance_float`

Comment: @B.Kelly, Okay. That was a valid point. I fixed the source code accordigly. However, why can't I work with Lennard-Jones's potential?

Comment: I would expect a harmonic function for two bonded atoms, or a morse. I would expect a LJ interaction if the atoms are not bonded to each other. For instance, an atom interacting with an atom in a different molecule would be lennard-jones. Another example of Lennard-Jones would be the the first atom in a polymer interacting with the last atom in the polymer. usually, if atoms are 4 or more atoms apart, they use LJ. it depends on the rules of the force-field. Most forcefields us harmonic for bonds,, as well as angles (2 atoms apart) and torsions for atoms 4 atoms apart

Comment: @B.Kelly, Please, post your comments as an answer. I will accept that to award the bounty.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Allen-Tildesley/examples/blob/master/python_examples/mc_chain_sw_module.py and the other codes for some helpful insights. I can post an answer in a bit, i may try making it all work as my intuition guides, later.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Have you figured this out now?

Comment: @NikeDattani, Yes. I have done it myself.

Comment: Would you like to answer the question? Or shall we close it?

Comment: @NikeDattani, better to close it.